# Submit without inputs

Tags: php, forms, pdo, submit

I'm looking to modify an SQL row just by clicking on a button.

I thought of doing a `<a href="validate.php?id=<?php echo $news->id; ?>">Validate the new</a>`.

All I want is to update a data in a row simply by clicking on a button, and it's the first time I'm facing this situation. Before now I always had to use `<inputs>`

But I think today this is not the best way to do that, may someone show me the best way to do that?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't correct?  Is there an *actual problem* that you're finding?  Does this *not work* in some way?

Comment: That should work, just remember to use $_GET as anchor links always populate $_GET

Comment: have you tried submitting a form with inputs as a `GET` query? You'll note that those inputs become query parameters in the url. you don't HAVE to have a form to submit data to a server, since a `GET` form goes in the url anyways. it's impossible for the server to tell the difference between a `<form method="get">` submission versus someone building the exact same submission url themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form that just contains a button:

```
<form method="POST" action="validate.php?id=<?= urlencode($news->id) ?>">
    <button type="submit">Validate the news</button>
</form>
```

You should prefer POST requests over GET requests when you modify resources (e.g. a news entry). The HTTP spec defines a GET request to have no side effects (like altering a news entry), POST is allowed to have side effects. And forms with POST are not followed and thus accidentally executed by search engines.